# SOLR Search relevance is in different order with AND statement

Tags: search, solr, solrnet

I use Solr version 3.6.2

I have indexed a field named "type", something like type1 type2 type3.

When I do a search without conditions in the query, I get a result with a certain relevance.
In this case all of the search results happen to be of type type1 type2 type3.

For example:

```
Result 1
Result 2
Result 3
```

But when I add a condition to the same query and explicity state that it should be of type1, type2 or type3 for example: `(query) AND (type:type1 OR type:type2 OR type:type3)`

For example:

```
Result 1
Result 3
Result 2
```

I get a different relevance as result, and I get different count of the results.

So I get different relevance if I add a condition that is already true.

Why this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it should look something like this instead:

```
text:(+query) and +type:(1 2 3)^0
```

^0 means that the second condition should be fulfilled but have no relavance!

Answer (score 1):

Try following operator with your query.

> Start with plus sign(**+**) = Must have in search result
>
> Start with power sign(**^**) = Relevance in search result (0 means no
>   effect of search result)

Compare to SQL Query

> Select * from Table1 Where text = 'xxx' And type in (1,2,3)